# Why does ?_escaped_fragment= react different than #!

Tags: ajax, web-crawler, bing, google-search-console

So per google specs for an AJAX crawlable site I setup my site so that foo.com/#!bar retrieves the content that it should. It also works when you type in foo.com/?_escaped_fragment=bar as it is essentially the same. However, if I go to fetch as google and render it, or even Bing's rendering preview service, only the /?_escaped_fragment= link returns a preview of the desired page the other #! link just returns the static homepage with nothing changed.
Now this is quite possibly because of the way I set up my site, the fragement/url plays no bearing on the PhP code, just onload or on hash change I see if either the #! or escaped fragment are called and convert them into what I need to call the PhP. Which goes against the apparent correct way of doing this. But if the the /?_escaped_fragment= works exactly as intended and the #! method is using the EXACT same code, why does #! return the static site?

Answer (score -1):

As I understood you use `#!` to generate diferent pages.

But `#` in url is use in HTML to get specific place on the same page - so maybe Google and Bing ignore this part of url.